# Check GPU PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

My PowerShell Script Optimizing Graphics Cards
So When i call GPU Tweaker it gives this error
the term "GpuTweaker" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet function script file or operable program
can some one edit my code ?

```
$GPU = (Get-WmiObject Win32_VideoController).Name
Function GPUTweaker{
    If ($GPU -like "*NVIDIA*") {
        <FunctionName>
    }

    If ($GPU -like "*AMD*") {
        <FunctionName>
    }

    If ($GPU -like "*Intel*") {
        <FunctionName>
    }
}
```

Comment: This error means that the function GpuTweaker is not defined in the current powershell context. @Sycho, where you call the function GPUTweaker?

Comment: @BETOMBO I fixed it 
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `-like` operator you should use wildcards, otherwise it'll not return desired result.

In my example:

```
C:\> $gpu = (Get-WmiObject Win32_VideoController).Name
C:\> $gpu 
Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620

C:\> $gpu -like "Intel"
False

C:\> $gpu -like "*Intel*"
True

C:\> $gpu -like "Intel*" 
True
```

See [about_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-like-and--notlike) for more examples.